# how can i call a String variale in a query?

Tags: android, string, sqlite

```
 public void savedate(String tblname,String time)
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_TABLE_NAME, tblname);
        values.put(COLUMN_TIME, time);
        String count ="select "+COLUMN_TABLE_NAME+" from "+TABLE_NAME+" where "+COLUMN_TABLE_NAME+ tblname;
        Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
        if(mcursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            long s = db.update(TABLE_NAME, values, COLUMN_TIME + "=? ", new String[]{time});
            if (s != -1)

                Toast.makeText(context, "updated, row id: " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "no change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            long s=db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
            if(s != -1)
                Toast.makeText(context, "inserted, row id: " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(context, "no_change", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }


    }
```

this is my code and this make an error that :

```
06-20 11:09:52.258    2001-2348/com.example.mytest.syncapp E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) no such column: college1
06-20 11:09:52.260    2001-2348/com.example.mytest.syncapp E/Webservice 1﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: college1 (code 1): , while compiling: select table_name from datesync where table_name= college1
```

sqlite table structure:
[image: sqlite table structure]

Comment: What is the value of `tblName` ?

Comment: whats the value of COLUMN_TABLE_NAME && TABLE_NAME

Comment: tblname  refres as field value of table_name here is college1;.                     the value of COLUMN_TABLE_NAME && TABLE_NAME are college1 and corresponding date

Answer (score 0):

Finally this code is executed......

String count ="select "+COLUMN_TABLE_NAME+" from "+TABLE_NAME+" where "+COLUMN_TABLE_NAME+ " = '" + tblname + "'";

```
    Cursor mcursor = db.rawQuery(count, null);
```